# Is the "routerLink" attribute inside an "a" element specific to Angular?

Tags: html, angular

Is the `routerLink` attribute, as found inside an `<a>` tag, something that is specific to Angular as opposed to being a general HTML attribute?

I am working on an Angular project and this is the attribute I want to use in my case. Here is a sample of it inside the code I am using (taken from an Angular tutorial):

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<nav>
    <a routerLink="/heroes"></a>
    <a router></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=routerlink - no hits. It's a directive: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.  It is an Angular directive, so it is something that is coming from Angular and not a vanilla HTML attribute.  It is, however retained as an attribute in the final HTML after Angular the two-step Angular compilation.